# How do I reuse a random result?

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var a = new Array(
"Jane",
"Tom,", 
"Alan,",
"Mary");
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(a[Math.floor(Math.random()*a.length)]);
</script>

ate an apple
```

Is there away of reusing the answer to `(a[Math.floor(Math.random()*a.length)])` later on in a script?

So for example I could later use text along the lines of `Harry asked "answer" if they had enjoyed the apple`

Answer (score 4):

You can store the answer in a variable

```
var ans = a[Math.floor(Math.random()*a.length)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to make this task

```js
var a = new Array("Jane","Tom,", "Alan,","Mary");
// use a varible named "answer" for get the valu of "a" array value.
var answer =a[getRandomArbitrary(0,a.length)];

alert(answer);

// can use the "answer" variable anywhere like this.
alert("Harry asked "+answer+", if they had enjoyed the apple");

/*
function for get the integer value between two numbers.
*/
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
    return parseInt(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
```